# console application return result only not whole aspx code

Tags: asp.net, api, controller, console, console-application

My aspx.page only has a json return but when I use console to call the aspx link it returns whole code. What do I need to change in order to get  only return form the aspx?

```
   static void Cloud()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient()) //WebClient  
        {
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json"); //Content-Type  
            client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");


            var result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:49299/test.aspx"); //URIhttp://localhost:49299/api/values/1  
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
```

[aspx code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQocY.png)
[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQzme.png)

Comment: What do you mean "return from aspx"? Looking at the image you posted, you seem to be referring to `Javascript` on the aspx page. Without a Javascript engine, like browsers do, none of that Javascript is invoked and the code above is doing exactly what it's expected to do - return the content of the resource being requested.

Comment: @EdSF I only want to get json result in console app not the whole page code

Comment: You will not get result from `Javascript` that isn't run. You will get the web page that the `Javascript` (source code) is in. **Your console app is not a web browser**. It does not know what to do with Javascript or even HTML, css, etc. for that matter. It will just show you the source.

Comment: @EdSF get it . Thanks !